# The constructor Category(String, String) is not visible - create constructor for some field using lombok?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lombok

I did googled a lot, still dont find any solution hence posting a question here..

I am developing Many-To-Many relationship example using lombok. I just want to create argument constructor for only two fields out of four. How we can do that ?

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer stockId;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String stockCode;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String stockName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "stock_category", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>(0);
}
```

**Category**

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 10)
    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "[DESC]", nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private String desc;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "categories")
    private Set<Stock> stocks = new HashSet<Stock>(0);
}
```

App.java

Why cant I set the limitted field constructor

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.setStockCode("7052");
        stock.setStockName("PADINI");

        Category category1 = new Category("CONSUMER", "CONSUMER COMPANY");
        Category category2 = new Category("INVESTMENT", "INVESTMENT COMPANY");

        Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();
        categories.add(category1);
        categories.add(category2);

        stock.setCategories(categories);

        session.save(stock);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). They are not helpful for those trying to fix your problem because we can't copy and paste the code the image shows. Instead, post [properly formatted code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Edit your question to remove the images of code and instead post it as a code block, along with an exception and I will be convinced that this post is not worthy of a downvote.

Comment: You receive up or downvotes for the quality of the input you provide. If you receive downvotes then look into improving your content instead of starting begging. To the contrary: asking to not downvote are something that can easily cause downvotes. Consider deleting your comments, and avoiding such statements in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that

> If `staticName` set, the generated constructor will be private, and an additional
>   static 'constructor' is generated with the same argument list that
>   wraps the real constructor.

Please, don't forget about `@NoArgsConstructor` because Hibernate needs it.